# differences in CSS between localhost and VPS

Tags: css, vps

After move website from localhost on my private VPS I have differences in CSS

Mainly:

- bigger font in some places
- doesn't work align

Before VPS I had website on taked out hosting and there everything was ok.

On VPS I installed everything myself - apache, php, mysql, ftp server.
The differences are on all browsers (FF,IE,Opera)

Server details:
Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny10 with Suhosin-Patch

I don't know what search... where. Why all on localhost displays correctly and on VPS differently. The same files!

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use firebug.  Check for 404ing of your css.

Make sure you have zoom set the same in both instances.

Other than that I don't have too many ideas...

Comment: The files CSS are loading ok. I checked zoom, it's normal. Everything is ok except a few details like bigger font and align ;/

Comment: what I'd do is open the two in side-by-side tabs, "Inspect element" with firebug and compare the CSS across the two.  If they're displaying different there should be a property showing differently and it'll tell you where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong.
In index file i had:

```
<?php   session_start();   ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

session_start() makes error and that was the reason.

After change on:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<?php   session_start();   ?>
```

Everything is ok.

Comment: A note from http://php.net/session_start that is a gotcha with your second method: **To use cookie-based sessions, `session_start()` must be called before outputing anything to the browser.**

Comment: Yeah. But the point is that session_start (in this moment) makes errors that's why I had problems with css.

Comment: Yes but now you've broken `session_start()` ;)

Comment: When I fix sessions I will change this :) Thanks for reply!